# Error when sudo apt update & refreshing software cache

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

I get a message sometimes telling me to upgrade to a supported version of Ubuntu for new updates. (currently 21.10) When I click OK on the popup, it closes without doing anything. Trying to upgrade through Settings by refreshing my software cache or going through the terminal, I get the following error -

```
pk-client-error-quark: 
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.(319)
```

Comment: 21.10 is EOL, and therefore updating from it is not supported anymore.

Comment: 21.10 is not anymore supported, so out of scope on this site. You will need to do a fresh install of 22.04.

Comment: @vanadium questions about upgrading to a supported release are on-topic though

Comment: @Ester not how to do that from an unsupported version, because you can't. Upgrading to a supported version means a fresh install of 22.04.

Comment: @Rinzwind we have one too, and I linked it above

Comment: @esther if it's EoL, that's what I'll do. Do I need to do the stuff before the "To upgrade to a new release" section, or is that just for keeping old releases? And what if anything needs backup before I upgrade?

Comment: the text of "To upgrade to a new release" does start with "Once you have performed the above steps" :) so yes, you do need to do the "above steps" also.

Comment: @esther and what about backing up?

Comment: always recommended, because things can go wrong and data can get lost. Unless you have nothing important and you wouldn't mind if everything got lost, in which case no backup is necessary.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/

Comment: **After** a release goes EOL, the repositories move to old-releases, which is why you have errors.  There is no set date this occurs; with 17.04 it was the day after, but sometimes it's weeks, even months... it's only listed as occurring **after** the EOL date.  You need to adjust your sources as per https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades  (or the duplicate link) then you should be able to *release-upgrade* correctly.  Ensure you have all upgrades applied first (*after correcting your sources for your EOL state*).

Comment: FYI:  You didn't state if you're using a server or desktop install; but you have an extra *upgrade via re-install* option for desktop installs that's faster & easier if using only Ubuntu repository software (ie. no or little 3rd party).  Backup first (*and data restores will be necessary if using server apps*)

Comment: also fyi:   21.10 (*impish*) tells you in the name it was the 2021-October release (add 2000 to year); so calculating the EOL is pretty easy... Add 9 months to 2021-October and you know it's 2022-July for EOL. That quick calculation tells you the month; assume it's the 3rd Thursday of the month & you're pretty close, or at worst a week off (*to get closer requires looking up release notes/dates*)